# how renderDynamicImport get access the resolved importee?

Tags: rollup

I want to get the resolved importee. For example:

```
import('@/utils')
```

the resolved one is like `xxx/src/utils.vendor.js`, I don't see any way to get the resolved value

the `left` and `right` can access it, but it's written in string, and not easy to write or test